Small stains on my bathroom ceiling. Should I be worried?
Pictures: https://imgur.com/a/MTtpnBS
These spots have been around for a few weeks now. Faint grey but noticeable enough. Completely solid to touch other than what feels to be a small hole (see picture with hairline crack).
I’m in a condo. There’s a bathroom directly above me but that area is just tiles. From other posts it seems like water leak is usually brown or yellow. Could it be moisture from my condenser fan?

do you see drops on the ceiling after hot shower

No drops. Just moisture

The spots indicate that something had infiltrated the ceiling drywall.  The most likely culprit is water.  Where that is coming from is unknown and will require some examination.

You can buy an inexpensive endoscopic camera that attaches to your phone for display, for about a yuppie food stamp.  Can you perhaps remove the vent fan grille and push the camera up between the metal box of the fan and the drywall to inspect what's going on above the ceiling?  (You may need to hog out a hole, but it should be easily covered by the grille.)
